# How can I select the most "steady" frames from a video with ffmpeg, where less motion occurs?

Tags: video, ffmpeg

I would like to use ffmpeg to select out frames from a video to make a preview picture. In the past I selected out frames manually: I extracted 1000 frames at equidistant time and then I picked out the most interesting ones, results were very nice and eye-catching but it is boring and waste of time. Then I tried to extract only the keyframes: I got much worse quality previews compared to the manual method. Now I am trying to extract frames which are good quality, eg, no blurry or with no motion. My command line is:

```
ffmpeg -loglevel info -i input_video.avi -vf select="lt(scene\,0.0001)*(isnan(prev_selected_t)+gte(t-prev_selected_t\,5))" -vsync 0  -f image2 -q 1  %09d.jpg
```

But I still get pictures with motion. Is there any better method to extract those frames which has less motion, eg. which are very similar to the prevoius and let's say to the second previous frame?

Comment: I would like to know answer to this too, it is surprising that nobody answered it for 5 years.